# Does my Nationality affect gameplay?

Tags: dirt-3

When creating a new profile, it asks you to choose your Nationality, giving you a pretty decent selection of countries to choose from. Not having played any of the earlier games in this series, I'm wondering if this choice has any ingame effect or if it's just for flavor.

Will the types of races or cars available, the order that things unlock, or the sponsors available to me change based on what I choose?

Comment: This question seems race-ist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has no effect on gameplay or availability of cars, tracks etc.

It is a feature of rally coverage and motor racing in general for the flag of the nationality of each driver to be displayed next to their name. It simply adds a degree of authenticity to the creation of your character.

This is based on my experience playing this series since its early days.